# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.endpointsapps'

Tags: python, django, path, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I am very new to python and linux, I was trying to create an app from a tutorial and this happend when I tried to run a test of my model.

```
(venv) kali@kali:~/machinelearning/backend/server$ python manage.py test apps.ml.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/kali/machinelearning/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/kali/machinelearning/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/kali/machinelearning/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/kali/machinelearning/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/kali/machinelearning/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.endpointsapps'
```

This is my first question on stackoverflow too

Answer (score 1):

Please add empty `__init__.py` file in the apps folder so that it can be recognized by Python as a package.

Check this link out. [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Can you please post the project structure you have? Basically just want to see where that apps exists.

Comment: Hey @Ajay-99336, If you got solution to your question, you can provide upvotes and accept answer if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an empty **init**.py (4 underscores in total) file in the apps folder for it to be recognized by Python as a package.

Have a look at the documentation for more informations.